# Chrome anchor underlining missing when programatically adding href

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have an anchor link tag with no href which correctly shows with no styling. I programatically add an href based on the text typed into a text input.

In Safari / Firefox, the link is underlined and changes colour as soon as something is typed into the text input (which is what I want).

However in Chrome, the link style doesn't change (but the href has been added and it is clickable). If I click on the link, the style is then applied.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I think this is because chrome doesn't recognise that the `any-link` pseudoclass now matches (since the link has an href) until the link is clicked, but I don't know why this would be the case - maybe something to do with reflow or repaint?

http://jsfiddle.net/76tyx4g0/

*Code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
  <script>
    function loadLink(field) {
      document.getElementById('the-link').href = "https://www.google.com?q=" + field.value;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="loadLink(this)">
<a id="the-link">The link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force repaint by setting scale to 1:

```
<script>
    function loadLink(field) {
        var newHref = "https://www.google.com?q=" + field.value;
        var link = document.getElementById('the-link');
        link.href = newHref;
        link.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
    }
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="loadLink(this)">
<a id="the-link">The link</a>
```

Comment: This workaround works - thanks! Any idea why this happens in the first place?

Comment: Well, browsers are constantly struggling for performance, so my guess is Google Chrome team just decided not to repaint the ui for such things.